# Cannot import modules in Python3 from sub directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

My current working files are in the following file structure:

```
--Trick_Folder (root folder)
   --try.py
  --LTransform (sub-folder)
     --encoder.py
     --decoder.py
     --sampler.py
     --__init__.py
```

in my `try.py` I try to write import one of the module from the sub-folder `LTransform` as follows:

```
**Python-3.4.3
from LTransform import encoder
```

(**Note**: In the `encoder.py` there is an `import sampler` line in it)

this is the error I am getting:

```
import sampler
ImportError: No module named 'sampler'
```

I tried understanding it but I can't wrap my head around it. The`__init__.py` is already in the sub-folder and my `PYTHONPATH` is set on the root-folder `Trick_Folder` as `/home/user/Trick_Folder`

Why can Python3 interpreter call the `sampler.py` when importing the `encoder.py` from the root folder(`Trick_Folder`)?

Answer (score 1):

To tell python to import from the current directory, use:

```
from . import sampler
```

in  your `encoder.py`

Comment: I tried that but it gives me `invalid syntax` I am running the `import` from `Python3 shell`

Answer (score 1):

Found the correct way for importing the module.

in my `encoder.py` where the line `import sampler` was previously before, as suggested by [this Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398442/python-relative-import-causes-syntaxerror-exception) I rewrote the line as suggested by @ahmed but with some changes since

```
import .sampler
```

gives an `invalid syntax` error

### Solution

```
from . import sampler
```

now `from LTransform import encoder` works perfectly.